# How to force UIPickerView.selectRow call didSelectRow method?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Is it possible to call `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` method, when running  `UIPickerView.selectRow(4, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`

or what is right way to archive this?

my implementation

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
textField.inputView = pickerView

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the UIPickerView delegate to be your controller.

Comment: no I have not, I want to call `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` from selectRow if it is possible

Comment: That method is part of the delegate protocol from *UIPickerView*. In order to get to call `didSelectRow`, you have to adopt to that delegate and implement it in your view controller. Then, assign the picker.delegate = self (or other view controller). Once in your code, you make `picker.selectRow(...)`, method `didSelectRow` will execute. You do not make a call directly to `didSelectRow`, that one is called once you select a row.

Comment: I don't see any difficulties of why you'd not call that method; you have implemented it, that is in your instance... what makes you paralysed to invoke that method _anytime you'd want_ exactly?

Comment: @Oxthor I have edited original post and added code sample, am I missing something?

Comment: just checked this on playground and it is not getting called here as well, maybe someone can explain why calling `selectRow` programatically does not invoke `didSelectRow`

Comment: I am sure its swift bug

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This to select the row

```
 self.yourPickerViewName.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

and this to trigger the method

```
 self.pickerView(self.yourPickerViewName, didSelectRow: 2, inComponent: 0)
```

Combine them to simulate user action

Comment: yes but not calls `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` method

Comment: thanks man, that hack works!! is it swift bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: what's the `pickerView` instance in the 2nd code line?

Comment: @TungFam it's explicit call to pickerView function (**didSelectRow**) as if it's an instance method of the class

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely not a bug that `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` is not called when you programatically select a row. Documentation says:

> Called by the picker view when the user selects a row in a component.

It's a delegate method which gets called only when a user selects a row. So naturally it won't get called if you select a row like this:

```
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

The hack in your accepted answer works, but it's not good practice to call delegate methods from your view controller. I suggest you to create another method which will do what you want when a row is selected by user or programatically:

e.g.

```
func doStuff(for row: Int, component: Int) {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

then in your delegate method:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    doStuff(for: row, component: component)
}
```

and when you select a row programatically:

```
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
doStuff(for: 0, component: 0)
```

If you need to do something with the pickerView in the `doStuff` method you can add another parameter and pass it along when you call it, or access pickerView variable directly.